# SCP Client in Go

Tags: ssh, go, scp

I was struggling with and [ssh client for golang](https://gist.github.com/linuz-ly/4148437) but was told that the ciphers for the freesshd server was incompatible with the ssh client for Go, so I just installed another one (PowerShell Server) and I can successfully connect to the server.

My problem is not over because I now need to transfer files from local to remote, and this can only be done through scp. I was directed to this [scp client for go](https://gist.github.com/jedy/3357393) and have two issues.

1. I run it and get this:
   [image]
2. Where or how can I access the contents of id_rsa needed for privateKey? I just went in my .ssh folder and saw a github_rsa and used that private key, I'm sure that this is not the correct one to use but wouldn't I see some kind of error or invalid private key and not the result above?

Comment: If the answer to solve the ciphers problem helped, remember to mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 3):

The code you were directed to is broken. The example also uses the public key authentication, which is not necessarily your only option. If you can allow password authentication instead, you can make it a bit easier for yourself.

I just made an upload myself by modifying the example you used:

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh"
    "fmt"
)

type password string

func (p password) Password(_ string) (string, error) {
    return string(p), nil
}

func main() {

    // Dial code is taken from the ssh package example
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "username",
        Auth: []ssh.ClientAuth{
            ssh.ClientAuthPassword(password("password")),
        },
    }
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
    }

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create session: " + err.Error())
    }
    defer session.Close()


    go func() {
        w, _ := session.StdinPipe()
        defer w.Close()
        content := "123456789\n"
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "C0644", len(content), "testfile")
        fmt.Fprint(w, content)
        fmt.Fprint(w, "\x00")
    }()
    if err := session.Run("/usr/bin/scp -qrt ./"); err != nil {
        panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this code but perhaps I'm missing something because it gives an error. it panics after the "session.Run()" and it says **Failed to run: Process exited with: 1. Reason was: ()** So if this ran successfully it would be possible to upload a file just by using the session.Run() in ssh?

Comment: You've now successfully compiled the code and connected to the SSH server. In theory, you can Run the scp command and feed it input through the `session.StdinPipe`. However, your program fails to Run scp most likely because you don't have it in the specified path: `/usr/bin/scp`

Comment: I have located an scp in my C:\cygwin64\bin, should I use this as the path? where exactly can I find the usr/bin?

Comment: I know Go, but I have hardly any experience with scp. Try changing /usr/bin/scp to C:\cygwin64\bin\scp and see if it works? /usr/bin is for Linux machines, not Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've changed it and ran it and it doesn't do anything and it doesn't close.

Comment: I entered "which scp" which would tell me if scp was available and shows the path as well. It gave me "usr/bin/scp" so I'm really confused on why this still gives errors.

Comment: The Code works - but only as long as I stick with strings which get written to files. If I change `content := "123456789\n"` to `content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)` I get `Process exited with: 1. Reason was:  ()`. The file is somehow copied, but mangled and has another md5. Why is that?