# Creating a file in ssh client for golang

Tags: ssh, go, scp

I have been struggling with this for around a week now. I have tried an [scp client for golang](https://gist.github.com/jedy/3357393) but was informed that the code was broken, and the contributed "fixed" code didn't work as well. Anyway, i'm giving up on file transferring and decided to just use ssh to create files and save on the remote machine.

I successfully ran the ssh client in [golang](https://gist.github.com/linuz-ly/4148437) before going into scp route so this may be a good solution.

In the ssh client it just executed the "ls" command and I am aware that there is a "touch" command to create a file.

```
var b bytes.Buffer
session.Stdout = &b
if err := session.Run("ls"); err != nil {
    panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(b.String())
```

Ultimately what I would like to achieve is read a local file maybe through `os.Open(localfile)` get it's contents then create a new file on the remote machine with the "touch" command then edit it and stick in the contents from the local file earlier. Or maybe there is a command that will make a new file and prepare it's contents already?

This looked promising, although this code gives me an error but from my observation, this would create a file called "testfile" with content of "123456789\n" then I think upload it using `session.Run("/usr/bin/scp -qrt ./");`?

```
    go func() {
    w, _ := session.StdinPipe()
    defer w.Close()
    content := "123456789\n"
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "C0644", len(content), "testfile")
    fmt.Fprint(w, content)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "\x00") // 传输以\x00结束
}()
if err := session.Run("/usr/bin/scp -qrt ./"); err != nil {
    panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
}
```

The above code can be found in my previous [question about scp in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021964/scp-client-in-golang/19022612?noredirect=1#19022612)

I'm not sure if this is what the code does, as I can't run it because of the error. I've tried to find out what the `/usr/bin/scp -qrt ./` command does although couldn't exactly understand it.

I've been on this project for a week now and is very frustrating. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "fixed" code in your last question works and compiles, unlike the original code. The problem is in the `Run` command; you might not have scp in that folder.

Comment: Thanks greg, I started with goftp, but tried to look for a more secure option.

Thanks ANisus, How do I find where scp is? Is there any documentation or resources for this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to write an scp client in go, and I came across your question in the process. I've got a lot closer to understanding it, so for now I'll just give you some direction to do this yourself. If I get any further I'll update my answer.

1. Your question about `scp -qrt`: this is 'remote scp' in 'sink' or 'to' mode. The scp client relies on another copy of scp being available on the remote host: `scp -t` being 'to'/sink mode, and `scp -f` being 'from'/source mode. Essentially `scp -f` will send back a short file 'header', followed by the contents of the file itself. `scp -t` simply expects to receive the same thing, for local storage.
2. For a good starting point (actually this gives pretty-much everything you need), [read this Oracle post](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works). It explains in detail what scp is doing.
3. For a good example in a similar language, see [this python implementation of scp](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py/blob/master/scp.py)

That should set you on your way. Cheers