# scp path in scp client for golang

Tags: ssh, go, scp

I have a [scp client in golang provided to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021964/scp-client-in-golang/19022612?noredirect=1#19022612) but been getting errors, I was informed that the problem was in this section.

```
if err := session.Run("/usr/bin/scp -qrt ./"); err != nil {
    panic("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
}
```

I was informed that the problem is that scp wasn't in the path, so searched for scp on and replaced the path which is "C:\cygwin64\bin"

I run it this time and it has no errors, although it just stays open and doesn't exit. I have ctrl+c to exit the program.

I am new to ssh and scp so I would appreciate all the help, Thanks.

Comment: First figure out what works on the command line. Then do it in go.

Comment: Hi, I type "which scp" which I found out would tell me if the scp command is available and its path. It gave me "usr/bin/scp". Still doesn't work though.

Comment: YOu have to figure out the entire command. What do you want to achieve? You haven't told us... What command achieves this (on the command line)? Then, and only then, implement it in go. You may be better off using a shell script

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for being unclear. This was frommy previous question, found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021964/scp-client-in-go/19022612?noredirect=1#comment28144258_19022612 . I was given a piece of code that would create and upload a file on the remote server, the code I entered above apparently is responsible for uploading the file(I don't exactly know, because I recieve errors). I was advised that the problem was in the session.Run() and maybe scp wasn't in the path specified, but after doing "which scp" the path is actually correct.

Comment: One more time: You need to first figure out what command on the command line works for you. Have you done so? You may consult superuser instead of stackoverflow for that. If you have a working command then come back here. You have only repeated yourself here instead of supplying us with the command input & output (that works)